# Hiding pydantic 2 field in fastapi (Query)

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I know this question has been asked and answered several times, but my question is a little bit different. Let's say we have a class with two fields and we don't want the end user to see the second field(I know, it is for developers and not end users). The obvious answer is having two separate class. In my googling I found some suggestions based on inheriting from BaseModel and overriding some methods. Just for curiosity I tried inheriting from BaseModel. Examples in internet were based on pydantic 1 and I am using pydantic 2 so I tried to adjust the solution. Result is something like this:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    visible_field: str
    hidden_field: str = Field(hidden=True)
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_json_schema__(
        cls, core_schema: CoreSchema, handler: GetJsonSchemaHandler
    ) -> JsonSchemaValue:
        json_schema = handler(core_schema)
        json_schema = handler.resolve_ref_schema(json_schema)
        props = {}
        for k, v in json_schema.get('properties', {}).items():
            if not v.get("hidden", False):
                props[k] = v
        json_schema["properties"] = props
        return json_schema
```

Now, if I use Body() like this:

```
def test_get(item:Item=Body()):
```

the result is as I expected. The hidden_field won't show up in the example (I know I can create my own example, that is not the point)

[image]

but if I try Depends:

```
def test_get(item:Item=Depends()):
```

the hidden_field will show up.

[image]

My question is, did I make a mistake in my code, or it is the expected behavior? If I have not made a mistake, is there any way to hide the field?
By the way, I am using python 3.10, FastAPI 0.105.0 and pydantic 2.5.2.

Comment: Usually you create `class Item(BaseModel): visible_field ..`, and then inherit from this class to your specific version: `class ItemWithDetails(Item): hidden_field`; you can then use `Item` as input/output where necessary, and create ItemWithDetails internally and use as required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am actually using inheritance in my code. I put it here without inheritance just for simplicity. Also, input/output means two separate classes and probably that is the best solution but I am just curious if there is a way to hide some fields, with overriding a method or some sort of tricks.